# How add class to parent element

Tags: javascript, jquery

This my code

```
$("#AllProducts li id:contains('" + serial + "')").addClass("backRed");
```

My span background became red but i need that my whole li to get background red

```
<li class="ui-draggable" value="301" style="display: list-item;">
<id>ID:301</id>
<br>
14k Gold Hebrew Name Necklace
<br>
Serial:( 101-01-001-01)
<br>
DefaultCat:( 313)
</li>
```

All works fine but any one know why this product  get backRed too?his li id not 303 but defaulcat is 303 but i checking the  $("#AllProducts li id:contains()... not the whole li

```
<li class="ui-draggable backRed" value="1163" style="display: list-item;">
<id>ID:1163</id>
<br>
Personalized Double Thickness Silver Name Necklace
<br>
Serial:( 101-01-073-04)
<br>
DefaultCat:( 303)
</li>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To select the parent use:

```
$("#AllProducts li span:contains('" + serial + "')").parent().addClass("backRed");
```

If you want the parent `li` use `.parent('li')`;

Comment: The `li` may not be the parent with the OP's selector. (It is in the example markup, of course.)

Comment: @T.J.Crowder that's very true but the question asked for "parent"

Answer (score 3):

Use [closest](http://api.jquery.com/closest/) :

```
$("#AllProducts li span:contains('" + serial + "')").closest('li')
     .addClass("backRed");
```

or [has](http://api.jquery.com/has/) :

```
$("#AllProducts li").has("span:contains('" + serial + "')")
      .addClass("backRed");
```

But the first one is clearer in my opinion and doesn't use an intermediate potentially heavy collection.

Comment: ...and `:has` has issues. :-)

Comment: @T.J.Crowder which kind of issues, performance ones or something else?

Comment: @roasted In my first version I used :has instead of .has and :has isn't recommended by jQuery for performance reasons.

Comment: @roasted: And there have been several bugs with it. Just had a quick look at the bug tracker and searching for ":has" didn't show any open ones, though, so here's hoping. The jQuery team do a great job jumping on bugs.